# dynamodb with help of np dynamodb or np vogels, throwing Invalid schema content error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, joi, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to create a schema using node package [dynamodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb)/[vogels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vogels) but it is throwing Invalid schema content. I used the below sample schema

```
var Account = vogels.define('Account', {
  hashKey : 'email',
 
  // add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
  timestamps : true,
 
  schema : {
    email   : Joi.string().email(),
    name    : Joi.string(),
    age     : Joi.number(),
    roles   : vogels.types.stringSet(),
    settings : {
      nickname      : Joi.string(),
      acceptedTerms : Joi.boolean().default(false)
    }
  }
});
```

error details

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid schema content: 
node_modules/vogels/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:731
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\hoek\lib\index.js:731
    throw new Error(msgs.join(' ') || 'Unknown error');
    ^

Error: Invalid schema content: 
    at Object.exports.assert (c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\hoek\lib\index.js:731:11)
    at Object.exports.schema (c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\joi\lib\cast.js:65:10)
    at internals.Object.keys (c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\joi\lib\object.js:269:25)
    at Object.exports.schema (c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\joi\lib\cast.js:46:33)
    at internals.Object.keys (c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\joi\lib\object.js:269:25)
    at Object.exports.schema (c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\joi\lib\cast.js:46:33)
    at internals.Object.keys (c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\joi\lib\object.js:269:25)
    at c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\lib\schema.js:105:74
    at internals.Object.internals.Any._validateWithOptions (c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\joi\lib\any.js:460:16)
    at module.exports.internals.Any.root.validate (c:\my-workspace\dynamoDB\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\joi\lib\index.js:102:23)
Process exited with code 1
```

Has anyone come across this or know how to create the schema using node page dynamodb/vogels?

Comment: Why you choose a library that wasn't updated in 5 years? For AWS it's enormous amount of time.

Comment: @karjan, Any suggestion on library to use for dynamodb? .

Comment: I'd suggest using aws-sdk. If you want to go with something like an ORM, Dynamoose is pretty nice. But it creates as many problems as it solves. In my opinion stay with aws-sdk

Comment: Thanks @karjan, I will consider your suggestion.